# Proof by induction of AM-GM inequality

Tags: inequality, induction, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I recently came up with
a proof
by simple induction
of the
arithmetic mean -
geometric mean inequality
that I haven't found here.
I'm sure it isn't new.

My questions:

(1) Is this correct?

(2) Is this new here?

Proof by induction
of AM-GM inequality
(AMGMI).

Statement.

If
$a_i > 0$ for
$1 \le i \le n$
then
$\left(\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i}{n}\right)^n
\ge \prod_{i=1}^n a_i
$
with equality only when
all $a_i$ are equal.

Proof.

For $n=1$,
this is
$\dfrac{a_1}{1}
\ge a_1$
which is true.

For $n=2$ this is
$\left(\dfrac{a_1+a_2}{2}\right)^2
\ge a_1a_2
$
which is the same as
$\left(\dfrac{a_1-a_2}{2}\right)^2
\ge 0
$
which is true
with equality only when
$a_1 = a_2$.

For the induction step,
we will use
Bernoulli's inequality
(BI)
in the form
$(1+x)^n
\ge 1+nx
$
for integer $n \ge 1$,
real $x > -1$
with equality only when
$x = 0$ or
$n = 1$.

Proof of BI.

True for $n = 1$.

If $n \ge 1$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
(1+x)^{n+1}
&=(1+x)^n(1+x)\\
&\ge (1+nx)(1+x)\\
&= 1+(n+1)x + nx^2\\
&\ge 1+(n+1)x\\
\end{array}
$

with equality only when
$x = 0$.

Now the proof.

Let
$S_m
=\sum_{i=1}^{m} a_i
$.

If AMGMI is true for
$n \ge 2$ then

$\begin{array}\\
\left(\dfrac{S_{n+1}}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}
&=\left(\dfrac{S_n+a_{n+1}}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\\
&=\left(\dfrac{\dfrac{n+1}{n}S_n-\dfrac{1}{n}S_n+a_{n+1}}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\\
&=\left(\dfrac1{n}S_n+\dfrac{-\dfrac{1}{n}S_n+a_{n+1}}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\\
&=\left(\dfrac1{n}S_n\right)^{n+1}\left(1+\dfrac{-1+\dfrac{na_{n+1}}{S_n}}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\\
&\ge\left(\dfrac1{n}S_n\right)^{n+1}\left(1+\left(-1+\dfrac{na_{n+1}}{S_n}\right)\right)
\qquad \text{(from BI since } \dfrac{na_{n+1}}{S_n} > 0)\\
&=\left(\dfrac1{n}S_n\right)^{n+1}\left(\dfrac{na_{n+1}}{S_n}\right)\\
&=\left(\dfrac1{n}S_n\right)^{n}a_{n+1}\\
&\ge\left(\prod_{i=1}^n a_i\right)a_{n+1}
\qquad\text{(induction hypothesis)}\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i\\
\end{array}
$

There is equality only when
all $a_i$ for
$1 \le i \le n$ are equal
(call the common value $a$)
and
$\dfrac{na_{n+1}}{S_n}
= 1
$
or
$a_{n+1}
=\dfrac{S_n}{n}
=a
$.

Comment: This might be related: [How do the Bernoulli's inequality gives the AM-GM?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1166222/42969). – Also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/692716/42969.

Comment: Haven't seen it yet. Actually looks like dream for students of high school. Great applying of Bernoulli inequality.

Comment: Is this the AM-GM proofs question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/691807/proofs-of-am-gm-inequality ... your proof is similar to some of these answer ?

Comment: I looked at that. My version isn't in it.

Comment: It seems to appear in one of my textbooks,

Comment: Which one? As I wrote, I'm sure it isn't new. However, I did discover it independently.