# Chrystal's proof of the arithmetic-mean-geometric-mean inequality

Tags: solution-verification, induction, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I was looking through
Chrystal's "Algebra, Part II"
(1900),
available for free on the web,
and I noticed that
it had a proof of the
arithmetic-mean-geometric-mean
inequality
by induction.

I have written it here in
more modern notation.

This is not a question -
I would like to make this
part of the
wiki.
How do I do that?

I find it interesting that
this proof uses the
product terms
rather than the sum terms
as I did in
[Proof by induction of AM-GM inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3811003/proof-by-induction-of-am-gm-inequality)

Chrystals's proof, page 46,
rewritten.

Suppose
$\frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k
\ge (\prod_{k=1}^n a_k)^{1/n}
$
or
$\sum_{k=1}^n a_k
\ge n(\prod_{k=1}^n a_k)^{1/n}
$.

Then
$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} a_k
\ge n(\prod_{k=1}^n a_k)^{1/n}+a_{n+1}
$.

If we can show that
$n(\prod_{k=1}^n a_k)^{1/n}+a_{n+1}
\ge (n+1)(\prod_{k=1}^{n+1} a_k)^{1/(n+1)}
$,
we are done.

$n(\prod_{k=1}^n a_k)^{1/n}+a_{n+1}
\ge (n+1)(\prod_{k=1}^{n+1} a_k)^{1/(n+1)}
$
is the same as,
dividing by $a_{n+1}$,
$n(\prod_{k=1}^n a_k/a^n_{n+1})^{1/n}+1
\ge (n+1)(\prod_{k=1}^{n+1} a_k/a^{n+1}_{n+1})^{1/(n+1)}
= (n+1)(\prod_{k=1}^{n} a_k/a^n_{n+1})^{1/(n+1)}
$.

Letting
$z
=(\prod_{k=1}^{n} a_k/a^n_{n+1})^{1/(n(n+1))}
$,
this is
$nz^{n+1}+1
\ge (n+1)z^n
$
or
$(n+1)(z^{n+1}-z^n)
\ge z^{n+1}-1
$
or
$(n+1)z^n(z-1)
\ge z^{n+1}-1
$.

If
$z = 1$
this is
$0 \ge 0$
which is true.

If
$z > 1$
this is
$(n+1)z^n
\ge \dfrac{z^{n+1}-1}{z-1}
=\sum_{k=0}^n z^k
$
which is true since
$z^n \ge z^k$.

If
$0 < z < 1$,
since
$z-1 < 0$,
dividing by $z-1$
reverses the inequality,
so
this is
$(n+1)z^n
\le \dfrac{z^{n+1}-1}{z-1}
=\sum_{k=0}^n z^k
$
which is true since
$z^n \le z^k$.