# AM - GM inequality with Bernoulli's inequality

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I am stuck on this proof: [The AM-GM
Inequality
is Equivalent
to the Bernoulli
Inequality](https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:981994/FULLTEXT01.pdf).

I get the first part with the Bernoulli Inequality, but how did he get from $\frac{A_n}{A_{n-1}}\ge \frac{x_n}{A_{n-1}}$ to $A_n^n\ge x_{n}A_{n-1}^{n-1}$
Can someone explain to me what I am missing there?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For other proofs that Bernoulli implies AM-GM see
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4198527/chrystals-proof-of-the-arithmetic-mean-geometric-mean-inequality
and
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3811003/proof-by-induction-of-am-gm-inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial inequality is not $\frac{A_n}{A_{n-1}} \ge \frac{x_n}{A_{n-1}}$ but $$\left(\frac{A_n}{A_{n-1}}\right)^n \ge \frac{x_n}{A_{n-1}}.$$ Multiplying both sides by $A_{n-1}^n$, we get
$$
\left(\frac{A_n}{A_{n-1}}\right)^n A_{n-1}^n \ge \frac{x_n}{A_{n-1}} \cdot A_{n-1}^n \implies A_n^n \ge x_n \cdot A_{n-1}^{n-1}.
$$